# C#: PointerPressed has been called twice when I click the image

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I am beginner in UWP. I wanna add a click event to an image that change `splitview`'s open-status. So I have an image in ma xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="image_1_6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="1225,559,-171,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Source="Assets\images.jpg" PointerPressed="image_1_6_PointerPressed"/>
```

I define `image_1_6_PointerPressed` as like as this:

```
private void image_1_6_PointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mySplitView.IsPaneOpen = !mySplitView.IsPaneOpen;
    }
```

But when I click on image the `mySplitView` open and close! Can any body help me on this please? Thanks.

Comment: If all else fails, you might as well try `if (mySplitView.IsPaneOpen == false) mySplitView.IsPaneOpen = true; else mySplitView.IsPaneOpen = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pointerpressed`doesn't working like as click event. It calls when you pressed and keep button and when you leave button event finishes. So when you click on image you think this event calls twice!
You should call `Tapped` event for this.

```
<Image x:Name="image_1_6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="1225,559,-171,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Source="Assets\images.jpg" Tapped="image_1_6_PointerPressed"/>
```

Comment: One thing I have added in the code behind method image_1_6_PointerPressed, add e.Handled = true; Then it won't call method more than needed.

Answer (score 0):

Until you diagnose, you can try something like:

```
  private bool pointerWorking = false;
  private void image_1_6_PointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!pointerWorking){
        pointerWorking = true;
        mySplitView.IsPaneOpen = !mySplitView.IsPaneOpen;
        pointerWorking = false;
    }
}
```

You can also try a different event

Comment: I've attempted this approach to prevent double calls when using the Pen input on a image canvas but it didn't work.