# PointerPressed vs Tapped

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

In my Win10 app the user can tap on the screen with the Surface Pen and place shapes on an image canvas. This works very well, however there is a bug where sometimes the app calls `PointerPressed` twice - resulting in two shapes being added.
I've tried moving the code to a Tapped callback. However the limitation is Tapped uses `TappedRoutedEventArgs^` and I cannot figure out how to get the same information as `PointerRoutedEventArgs^`.
I use currently use...

```
onPenTouched(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerRoutedEventArgs^ e){

   PointerPoint^ p = e->GetCurrentPoint(imgCanvas);

   if (p->Properties->IsEraser){
        //do stuff
   }
}
```

To determine which end of the pen is being used.
How can I get this information from `TappedRoutedEventArgs`?

I've attempted the solution suggested in [this almost-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463158/c-pointerpressed-has-been-called-twice-when-i-click-the-image) that suggests using a bool flag to prevent double calls but this doesn't work.

**UPDATE**
Using the suggested workaround from [Jayden Gu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527203/jayden-gu-msft) achieves the goal of being able to obtain `PointerPoint^` however the properties aren't as expected. Debugging the output like this...

```
OutputDebugString(p->Properties->IsEraser.ToString()->Data());
OutputDebugString(p->Properties->IsInverted.ToString()->Data());
OutputDebugString(p->Properties->IsPrimary.ToString()->Data());
```

Looks like the following

```
Tapping with pen tip =  false false true  
Tapping with pen eraser = false true true  
Tapping with finger = false false true
```

For now I'll have to use the `IsInverted` property to detect if the erase is being used. Hopefully it will be a reliable and stable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we tap the Control, the `PointerPressed` event will be fired and the `Tapped` event will be fired after the `PointerPressed` event. When we tapped Control two times quickly, the Tap event will be fired once. Only the `PointerPressed` will be fired when we tap the Control second time. It is by design.

If you want get the `Point` in `Tapped` event, we can use the `TappedRoutedEventArgs.GetPosition` method to get the point.

If you want get `PointerRoutedEventArgs` in `Tap` event, as a workaround, we can define a `TappedRoutedEventArgs` property in your code. We can set the `TappedRoutedEventArgs` of the `PointerPressed` to it in the `PointerPressed` event. That we can get the `TappedRoutedEventArgs` in the `Tap` event.

For example:

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerRoutedEventArgs^ nowPointerRoutedEventArgs;


void App2::MainPage::Rectangle_Tapped(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Windows::UI::Input::PointerPoint^ p = nowPointerRoutedEventArgs->GetCurrentPoint(imgCanvas);
}

void App2::MainPage::Rectangle_PointerPressed(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    nowPointerRoutedEventArgs = e;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works...however, 
p->Properties->IsEraser always returns false when tapping with the eraser.
p->Properties->IsInverted returns true when using the eraser (false with pen tip) So I could use this detect which end of the pen is being used but it doesn't feel like it'll be as robust.